# Reading next available QByteArray in a for loop

Tags: qt

I am reading a `QByteArray (output)` line by line in a for loop and assign each line to a `QString (lineText)`. If that text contains an error message, it is catch. But the reason of that error is read out in the next two or three lines. My goal is to catch if that string contains an error text, read immediately next lines to catch the reason.

```
QList<QByteArray> list = output.split('\n');
for (auto iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter)
{
  QString lineText = QString::fromLatin1(*iter); 
  
  if (lineText.contains("Request Failed"))
  {
    QString error = lineText.split("0006:031b")[1]; // not valid 
    
    //Read next three line entries here
  }
}
```

Comment: You already know how to read a line. So just do that 3 times in a row. I don't understand what part you're having trouble with.

Comment: I assume you want to see if it contains error and read it in single line? If so then you could do this

QString error = (lineText.contains("0006:031b") ?  lineText.split("0006:031n")[1] : QString(""));

Comment: Actually no. I want to just read next possible three lines from the list if that error occurs.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve.  You have a comment in your code `// not valid`: what's not valid?  Note that if the string `0006:031b` doesn't appear in `lineText` then accessing index 1 of the returned `QStringList` will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: The original ```lineText``` consist of the ```Request Failed: 0006:031b Failed to establish association``` string. Using ``split("0006:031b")[1]`` I am just getting the ``Failed to establish association`` part of the whole string.  I am sure, in the next three lines, there are more information, why this error is occurred. Therefore, I want to read those next lines to figure out what is the exact reason.